# Can I config development server IP in react native app (ios)?

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios

So the problem is I'm developing react native on 2 different machines. 1 machine I can't run xcode to build. So I'm hoping that I can build the app on one machine, and when I have to continue develop on the other machine, I can just change the IP of the development server config on the app. From [facebook doc](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device.html), it seem the android app will let you config the IP from developer menu, but the ios app can't. Is there anyway to get around that? (Change the native ios app to make it configurable, maybe?)

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try this in appDelegate.m -> jsCodeLocation = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8081/example/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true"];

Comment: @JainZz yes, but then I would need xcode to rebuild the app. I'm looking for ways that I can change the IP without rebuilding the app. Looks like the android app can do that, but I don't know why the ios app can't.

Comment: I think the only way is to do in Xcode... Please let me know that If you get any other solution :)